# Outlook VSTO add-in setup error after installation

Tags: windows, vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I created an addin with VSTO and a setup project with visual studio installer.
Im totally new on creating setups... and im getting something weird here (most likely a rookie problem).

I have what follows...
[image]

When i install, files get deployed into the folder, like below... and i suppose its the way it should be.

[image]

But when i try the addin, i get the following error, like if the manifest is pointing to a different path:
[image]

Then for the sake of testing i copied the manifest into the folder he seeks, like so:
[image]

And them, the add-in loads correctly...

Though I **need some guidance with 2 scenarios**:

- where or **how can i fix this pointing to that folder?**
- **Is there a way to perform a delete on a specific registry key when program is uninstalled?**

Please i have this important job to finish at my work and im burning nails...

**Many thanks in advance** for your time taken to read and help.

Answer (score 1):

Before installing the add-in make sure it is unregistered (if you debugged the project previously there). Also make sure that your installer added [Registry entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) on the target machine that correspond to the actual location.

In general, make sure that you did all the steps describe in the following articles (depends on what installer you chose for deploying the add-in):

- [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019)
- [Deploying a VSTO Solution Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I actually went to check where that path was being set... and it was on the .vsto file. It was set like: Application Files\SenderEmailProperty_1_0_0_10\SenderEmailProperty.vsto

But i removed the path "Application Files\SenderEmailProperty_1_0_0_10\".

Now i get another issue... it says that the .vsto XML signature is invalid. Even after deleting, cleaning, uninstalling... and setting the path back, it says the signature is invalid. =\\

Answer (score 0):

Started a new project and copied all the code from the previous one... started working.
I cannot understand what witchery Visual Studio does some times.